# Почему своевременно не очищаются сессионные куки, используя браузер Google Chrome?

Tags: php, yii2, cookie, google-chrome

Я использую стандартный демо-пример аутентификации пользователя (где нужно ввести в форму ввода логин и пароль `admin`) в фреймворке Yii-2.
Я устанавливаю время жизни кукам равное 60 секундам:

```
public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 60 : 0);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Когда проходит 60 секунд, я делаю рестарт браузера для закрытии сессии, и после этих манипуляций, зайдя снова на сайт, я почему-то прохожу аутентификацию.

Хотя время жизни куков 60 секунд и после рестарта браузера сессия должна закрываться, этого не происходит. Надо отметить, что куки удаляются. Может, не все, а только те, в которые мы передаем информацию. На мой взгляд, очень странно, что я прохожу аутентификацию.

Это поведение наблюдается в браузере Google Chrome, в FF такого нету.

То есть, понятно, что  это  связанно с особенностью самого браузера **Google Chrome**.

---

**Далее:**

Те куки которые содержат данные (`authKey`, `accessToken` ... и.т.д) **которые мы передаём в них**, будут удаляться по истечении указанного времени.

```
Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(),60);
```

**Но, несмотря на это**, стандартный метод Yii-2 проверки аутентификации, покажет что мы залогинены, хотя те куки которые содержали в себе ту информацию которую мы передавали в них, уже будут удалены.

```
Yii::$app->user->isGuest
```

---

Конечно, можно в конфигурационном файле приложения добавить подобные свойства:

```
'authTimeout' => 10
```

но в таком случае, для всех пользователей будет установлено единое время аутентификации, и чекбокс (запомнить логин и пароль) потеряет свою актуальность для тех посетителей, которые не захотят сохранять аутентификацию.

**Вопрос** : Почему я прохожу аутентификацию, что разработчики там такое используют, что даже после удаления тех кук, которые содержат в себе информацию о пользователе, я всё равно могу проходить аутентификацию? На основе каких данных проходит аутентификаця? Как сделать, чтобы всё работало правильно?

Comment: Т.к.  есть еще сессия.... во фреймворке у  `Yii::$app->user` в методе `yii\web\User::renewAuthStatus()` сначала ищется `ID` пользователя в сессии. А если в сессии не найдено, то кука. Так что если время жизни сессии 1 час, а вы ставили время кук 1 минуту, то логично что останитесь залогиненым.....нужно манипулировать еще либо временем сессии `session => timeout` либо временем авторизации юзера `user => authTimeout`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Прошло около 8 часов. В течении этого времени,компьютер перезагружался, браузер закрывался. При запуске сайта, все равно происходит аутентификация. Она же не должна быть. Кстати, сессии обычно закрываются  при закрытии самого браузера. А что такое время авторизации юзера, куки?

Comment: Сессия не закрывается с закрытием браузера... Кто из неквалифицированных специалистов вам это сообщил? Она живет на серверной стороне и ей пофиг до браузера абсолютно.....почти....Она может жить даже спустя несколько месяцев, в зависимости от настроек сервака....лично у моего сервака по дефолту в пхп ини время сессии стояло 180000000. Не исключено и у вас аналогичное...Как думаете это 8 часов?))

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский в конфиге PHP :session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440 -время жизни сессии по умолчанию. Что мы делаем: устанавливаем `login($this->getUser(), 60)` на 60 и или 1500 секунд,  время жизни кукам. Переводим часы на 3 дня вперед, перезагружаем все, запускаем, переходим на стандартный пример сайта где ранее мы уже прошли аутентификацию, но `Yii::$app->user->isGuest`, так-же показывает, что мы аутентифицировались,когда он должен был показать обратное.

Comment: А причем тут гость? Ахахах. Опять игра в экстрасенсов. Понятно. Я даже уже примерно представляю о чем на самом деле вы спрашиваете, но опять не так сформулировали вопрос)) ... по поводу гостя - разумеется, если вы не вошли в систему под каким-либо лог пасом, а просто гуляете по сайту вы всегда будете гостем и система всегда будет об этом знать и говорить об этом... т.к. у нее есть проверка `getIsGuest`  где она проверяет идентификацию пользователя `getIdentity()`.... и если она есть - то идут проверки личности, а если `getIdentity() === null;` то вы - гость. Это и логично.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  1.Запускаем Yii2 с стандартным демо-примером аутентификации (переходим на страницу ввода логина и пароля)  . 2. Вводим логин и пароль - demo/demo. 3.Закрываем браузер на 3 дня и  перезагружаем локальный веб-сервер. 4. Открываем браузер и возвращаемся на наш сайт. 5.`Yii::$app->user->isGuest`  проверка на гостя определяет что мы уже прошли аутентификацию, то есть, что она нам  не нужна.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Если куки уже давно истекли , вместе с сессиями, то `Yii::$app->user->isGuest` соответственно должен был возвратить значение с отрицательным результатом для нас, который нам сообщит о том, что текущий пользователь является гостем, то есть, не аутентифицирован.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский А вы смотрели стандартный пример SiteController? Видели эту конструкцию: `if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest){}` ? То есть, если равно NULL то мы не гость. Если равно true или оно же просто "1", то мы Гость.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  Да, кстати, вы уверены в том что написали? Алексей Шиманский: Сессия не закрывается с закрытием браузера...

Comment: а у вас субдомены не вовлечены здесь? а то там если сессионные куки с дефолтным именем у всех - могут перекрываться с основного домена

Comment: @kroder Нет. ___________

Comment: Юрий, откуда вы знаете что куки ставятся именно с таким временем? Заголовки смотрели?

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов, пожалуйста, потрудитесь указать, какие важные детали я удалил при правке вопроса и в чем заключается коверканье? С примером, пожалуйста.

Comment: @VenZell  Этот вопрос относится не к Google Chrome, а к фраемворку Yii-2. Проблема не в Google Chrome, а в работе или настройки  самого фраемворка.  Я уже не помню какие именно детали вы удалили, а примерно:  Сам заголовок вопроса был составлен не верно, потому что указывал на другую проблему не связанную с этой.  Но дело не ограничилось самим заголовком, в тексте самого вопроса так-же были удаленный важные детали. Давайте лучше я сам всё подредактирую?

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов, кардинально был изменен заголовок на основе вашего текста вопроса. Ни одной детали из вопроса удалено не было. Можете убедиться в истории правок. Сейчас заголовок это сложночитаемый набор слов. Дело ваше.

Comment: @VenZell Спасибо, правки по делу. Может быть поможете мне с моим вопросом ? - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503666/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B4-%D0%B2-yii2

Comment: @VenZell Там написано ппц какое-то в офф справочнике. Если интересует, опишу сейчас подробнее, или тогда опишу чуть позже.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Известно, что при определённых настройках Google Chrome [не удаляет сессионные куки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies), которые в других браузерах удаляются при закрытии.

- [Исследование по вашему вопросу на форуме Yii Framework.](http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8821)
- [Как в Chrome удалить куки созданные за последнее время без перезапуска.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582)

---

Если вам нужно чтобы сессия форсированно очищалась через 60 секунд, то можно сделать так. В файле `index.php` между `require_once` и `Yii::createWebApplication` добавьте следующий код:

```
<?php
require_once($yii);

/* Начало */

// если у нас есть сессионная кука...
if (!empty($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    // сначала явно начнем сессию
    session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE && session_start();
    // если сессия свежая (то есть нет нашей пометки о последнем использовании)
    if (empty($_SESSION['LAST_USE'])) {
        // запишем когда сессия начата
        $_SESSION['LAST_USE'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
    } else {
        // иначе считаем что сессия старая, значит нужно проверить 
        // что сессия не истекла =>
        // если последнее обращение было позже чем 60 секунд назад...
        if ($_SESSION['LAST_USE'] < $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] - 60) {
            // обнулим сессию
            session_destroy();
            $_SESSION = [];
            // и начнем её заново, раз она уже была
            session_start();
        } else {
            // последнее обращение было только что, 
            // сбросим время последнего использования
            $_SESSION['LAST_USE'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
        }

    }
}

/* Конец */

Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вы на 50% вопроса ответили.  Вот еще 50% - как сделать чтобы всё работало правильно?

Comment: Если Вы не знаете, пожалуйста, сообщите мне об этом.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов откуда вы знаете что куки ставятся, и что кук нет? В вашем вопрос не показано что вы убедились что работа с куками производится так, как вы думаете

Comment: Юрий, откуда вы знаете что кука ставиться со сроком жизни в 60 секунд?

Comment: Я проверял, тестировал в разных браузерах. Я видел время экспирации, время её жизни, она обычно указывается в панеле для разработчиков. После 60 секунд она удаляется.  Это я сейчас пишу об обычной куки, не сессионной.Еще, если Вы не знаете как сделать что бы всё работало, сообщите мне об этом, пожалуйста. Приятного Вам дня.

Comment: Юрий, вы видели заголовки, которыми устанавливается кука? Можно ли увидеть эти заголовки в вашем вопросе?

Comment: Зачем эта информация нужна вам, когда они и так отрабатывают как надо, то есть, удаляются по времени?  `Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=7usi31jdm651v165k6ggdp8mr1; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:_identity=99dd664344a25f795db3ce19da0a04a0abb54e63fda8e4944771cc3bff190382a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A9%3A%22_identity%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A23%3A%22%5B%22100%22%2C%22test100key%22%2C60%5D%22%3B%7D; expires=Wed, 16-Mar-2016 03:02:03 GMT; Max-Age=60; path=/; httponly`

Comment: Если они удаляются, тогда в чём ещё проблема?

Comment: Я об этом как раз и написал в своём вопросе. Они то удаляются, но не удаляются сессионные куки из-за того что гуглхром их сохранят. Но, как так сделать, что бы гугл хром не влиял на аутентификацию? 1.Можно очищать данные о пользователях методом - ` 'authTimeout' => 10` , но тогда эти данные будут очищаться для всех. Как в таком случаи динамически делать очистку этих данных на сервер, то есть не через логаут, а по типу метода `authTimeout` только динамически, отдельно для каждого пользователя?

Comment: Можно сохранять внутри `$_SESSION` время последнего обращения к сессии. Перед очередным сохранением проверять когда то было. Если последнее обращение к сессии было больше чем X секунд назад - сессию очищать.

Comment: Как в Yii2 это реализовать ? В своём ответе это опишите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов добавил

Comment: Поздравляю Вас! )Всё работает, спасибо. Не могли бы Вы ответить на еще один вопрос - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503666/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B4-%D0%B2-yii2